# How to skip specific line from csv file using fgetcsv function

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have function which read csv file in the array. my code is

```
public function csvExtract() 
     {   


       $file_handle = fopen(text.csv, 'r');

       while (!feof($file_handle) )
        {
            arraydata[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }

        fclose($file_handle);
    }
```

what i need is:

my file contain last row which has `FINAL TOTAL`  that row i want to skip .

how to do this. Can any one help me on this.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip any loop in PHP with the [`continue`](http://www.php.net/continue) statement. This will only skip **1** iteration of the loop, as apposed to the [`break`](http://www.php.net/break) statement, which will end the loop completely.
Using this, you can form a condition for when the loop should skip:

```
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $csv = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    // check your condition and skip if needed...
    if (in_array('FINAL TOTAL', $csv)) continue;
    $data[] = $csv;
}
```

Comment: thank you NDM.  but here one small problem when i used this it is giving me warring as follows :Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in 99 where line 99 have this statement    if (in_array('FINAL TOTAL', $csv)) continue;

Comment: Well, you have to make sure the code in the `if` is correct for your data, also be sure to check if `fgetcsv` returns an array, as it returns `false` on failure

Answer (score 2):

Once you've finished your read loop:

```
end($arraydata);
$key = key($arraydata);
unset($arraydata[$key]);
```

or simply

```
array_pop($arraydata);
```

Answer (score 0):

quick dirty solution

```
 ...
 fclose($file_handle);
 if($arraydata) {
    unset($arraydata[count($arraydata)-1)]);
 }
```

just "delete" the last row from your import